# Dynamic array creation

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a testing offline application which is supposted to serve as a e-bay for selling hard copy music(like discogs). Users would be able to sell and buy records (it is a test app so credit is represented as a simple variable). I have two dynamic arrays: one for items and one for users both arrays are in Session class which is responsible for data manipulation. Arrays are saved to binary files and loaded at startup. My main issue is that I am not able to manipulate with the user list array although I can do anything with the array of items. I have ommited most of the code to keep it simple, and the following is just the important part.

```
class User {
    string password;
    string username;
    int credit;
}

class Item {
    string name;
    string label;
    int price;
}

class Vinyl:public Item{}
class Disk:public Item{}

class Session{
    Item **itemlist;
    User **userlist;

    Session() {
        itemlist=new Item*[100];
        userlist=new User*[100];
    }

    void CreateItem(string name,string label,int price,) {
        itemlist[lsize]=new Vinyl(name,label,price);
    }

    void CreateUser(string uname, string pass) {
        list[usize]=new User(uname,pass,count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever you want a "dynamic array" in C++ you should automatically think [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Tagged `c++14` yet using `new` and pointers-to-pointers. Mother. Of. God.

Comment: I'm also worried when you say that the "arrays are saved to binary files", do you save only the pointers? Do you save the structures "as is"? Neither will work very well, and you really should learn about [*serialization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Comment: The saving process is still in developement, but I would like to save/load the whole structures. @ildjarn Sorry for unclear spec but I am lerning c++ right now so the spec could be misleading.

Answer (score -1):

Your question somehow managed to not make it to the text you wrote. But anyway, use [**`std::vector`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). That's what it's for (and it will undoubtedly solve whatever the problem is, out of the multitude indicated by the code).

Comment: I downvoted to the question, I flagged it to close it as unclear, and I downvoted to your answer because it seems a random answer to a poor question.